# Java: Getting a different result in runnable jar compared to eclipse

Tags: java, executable-jar

So I've been making a game for someone's birthday, I finally finished, but I'm having issues exporting it into a runnable jar file. What the game is is similar to "Who wants to be a millionaire", so it opens a window asking the contestant their name, then it goes on to ask the questions. At the end, it opens a letter that I wrote to them.

Now for the actual issue. I run the project in Eclipse and it works like a charm. However when I run it as a jar, I get the name prompt, then it all closes down. I don't get any error messages that I can see. I've tried running it through command prompt to see if anything would happen but no dice. Any help would be greatly appreciated with this!

EDIT: Below is my Start class and my JGame class:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

public class start {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
    SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date bday = sdformat.parse("2020/02/01");
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    String toda = dtf.format(now);
    Date today = sdformat.parse(toda);
    if (today.after(bday)) {
        new JWelcome();
    } else {
        new JWrongDate();
    }
}

}
```

JGame:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class JGame extends JWin {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JLabel jlabel;
private JWelcome jwelcome;
private JGWindowListener jgwl;
private JGMBar jgmb;
private JPanel northpanel;
private JPanel centerpanel;
private JPanel eastpanel;
private JPanel jsouthpanel;

private JButton jbutton_A;
private JButton jbutton_B;
private JButton jbutton_C;
private JButton jbutton_D;
private JButton jbfifty_fifty;
private JTArea jtarea;
private JGameListener jgml;
private JFile jfile;
private JFile jfile_A;
private JFile jfile_B;
private JFile jfile_C;
private JFile jfile_D;
private JFile jsolution;
private String answer_A;
private String answer_B;
private String answer_C;
private String answer_D;
private String solution;
// private JLabel jwon;

private int index;

public JGame(JWelcome jwelcome) throws ParseException {
    super();
    this.jwelcome = jwelcome;
    jgwl = new JGWindowListener(this);
    jgml = new JGameListener(this);
    jgmb = new JGMBar(this);
    setTitle("Brigit's Birthday Game");
    setSize(800, 300);

    jlabel = new JLabel("Hello " + jwelcome.getJTArea().getText() + "! Welcome to your birthday game!");

    jtarea = new JTArea("Question");

    jfile = new JFile();
    jfile_A = new JFile();
    jfile_B = new JFile();
    jfile_C = new JFile();
    jfile_D = new JFile();
    jsolution = new JFile();

    index = 0;
    jtarea.setText(jfile.loadQuestions("Questions.txt", index));

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
    jtarea.scrollRectToVisible(r);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // jwon = new JLabel("Select the correct answer");
    northpanel = new JPanel();
    northpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    northpanel.add(jlabel);
    northpanel.setBackground(Color.magenta);
    getContentPane().add((BorderLayout.NORTH), northpanel);
    addWindowListener(jgwl);
    setJMenuBar(jgmb);

    centerpanel = new JPanel();
    centerpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    centerpanel.add(jtarea);
    centerpanel.setBackground(Color.magenta);

    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, centerpanel);

    jbfifty_fifty = new JButton("50:50");
    jbfifty_fifty.addActionListener(jgml);

    eastpanel = new JPanel();
    eastpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    eastpanel.add(jbfifty_fifty);
    eastpanel.setBackground(Color.magenta);

    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, eastpanel);

    // jfile_A.loadQuestions("Answers_A.txt", 0
    answer_A = (String) jfile_A.loadQuestions("Answers_A.txt", index);
    answer_B = (String) jfile_B.loadQuestions("Answers_B.txt", index);
    answer_C = (String) jfile_C.loadQuestions("Answers_C.txt", index);
    answer_D = (String) jfile_D.loadQuestions("Answers_D.txt", index);
    solution = (String) jsolution.loadQuestions("Solutions.txt", index);

    jbutton_A = new JButton("A: ");
    jbutton_B = new JButton("B: ");
    jbutton_C = new JButton("C: ");
    jbutton_D = new JButton("D: ");

    jbutton_A.setText("A: " + answer_A);
    jbutton_B.setText("B: " + answer_B);
    jbutton_C.setText("C: " + answer_C);
    jbutton_D.setText("D: " + answer_D);

    jsouthpanel = new JPanel();
    jsouthpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    jbutton_A.addActionListener(jgml);
    jbutton_B.addActionListener(jgml);
    jbutton_C.addActionListener(jgml);
    jbutton_D.addActionListener(jgml);

    jsouthpanel.add(jbutton_A);
    jsouthpanel.add(jbutton_B);
    jsouthpanel.add(jbutton_C);
    jsouthpanel.add(jbutton_D);

    jsouthpanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    jsouthpanel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, jsouthpanel);
    setVisible(true);
}

public JButton getJButton_A() {
    return jbutton_A;
}

public JButton getJButton_B() {
    return jbutton_B;
}

public JButton getJButton_C() {
    return jbutton_C;
}

public JButton getJButton_D() {
    return jbutton_D;
}

public JFile getFile_A() {
    return jfile_A;
}

public JFile getFile_B() {
    return jfile_B;
}

public JFile getFile_C() {
    return jfile_C;
}

public JFile getFile_D() {
    return jfile_D;
}

public String getAnswer_A() {
    return answer_A;
}

public String getAnswer_B() {
    return answer_B;
}

public String getAnswer_C() {
    return answer_C;
}

public String getAnswer_D() {
    return answer_D;
}

public String getSolution() {
    return solution;
}

public JPanel getSouthPanel() {
    return jsouthpanel;
}

public JFile getJFile() {
    return jfile;
}

public JTArea getJTArea() {
    return jtarea;
}

public int getIndex() {
    return index;
}

public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}

public JLabel getJLabel() {
    return jlabel;
}

public void setJLabel(JLabel jl) {
    jlabel = jl;
}

public JButton getFifty() {
    return jbfifty_fifty;
}

int nextQuestion() throws IOException {
    try {
        index = index + 1;
        if (index >= 20) {
            File file = new File("letter.docx");

            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            if (file.exists())
                desktop.open(file);

            setIndex(0);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    jtarea.setText(jfile.loadQuestions("Questions.txt", index));
    answer_A = (String) jfile_A.loadQuestions("Answers_A.txt", index);
    answer_B = (String) jfile_B.loadQuestions("Answers_B.txt", index);
    answer_C = (String) jfile_C.loadQuestions("Answers_C.txt", index);
    answer_D = (String) jfile_D.loadQuestions("Answers_D.txt", index);
    solution = (String) jsolution.loadQuestions("Solutions.txt", index);
    jbutton_A.setText("A: " + answer_A);
    jbutton_B.setText("B: " + answer_B);
    jbutton_C.setText("C: " + answer_C);
    jbutton_D.setText("D: " + answer_D);

    return index;
}

void play() {
    jlabel.setText("Select one of the four answers");
    jbutton_A.addActionListener(jgml);
    jbutton_B.addActionListener(jgml);
    jbutton_C.addActionListener(jgml);
    jbutton_D.addActionListener(jgml);
}

void pause() {
    jlabel.setText("pause");
    jbutton_A.removeActionListener(jgml);
    jbutton_B.removeActionListener(jgml);
    jbutton_C.removeActionListener(jgml);
    jbutton_D.removeActionListener(jgml);
    jsouthpanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(JGame.class.getResource("baloons.jpeg"));
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
}

void close() {
    dispose();
    setVisible(false);
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

EDIT 2:
Here is the command used to run my game:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\javaw.exe -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "C:\Users\neilp\eclipse-workspace\Brigit Birthday Quiz\bin" start
```

Comment: Any code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Eclipse, choose item ___Run Configurations...___ from _Run_ menu. In the _Run Configurations_ window, click on button _Show Command Line_ This will show you the actual command that Eclipse uses to run your game. Also [edit] your question and post the command you use to launch your runnable JAR file.

Comment: Added the information y'all asked for. Thanks for helpin'

Comment: The argument to `-classpath` option of `java` command must be the path to the actual JAR file and not the directory that the file is in. Add the name of your JAR file.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how to modify the command though. When I click Show Command Line it doesn't allow me to edit anything. Or am I missing the point here?

Comment: Maybe not helping with your question: By mixing outdated and modern date and time classes, you are over-complicating things. Just stick to `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and forget about the old `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`.